# How to call locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization function multiple times? Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ibeacon

I built an ionic app that uses Beacons plugin which in turn uses `LocationManager` plugin. [This is the tutorial I followed.](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/support-ibeacons-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/)

As you know on iOS it requests user to allow the app to use location. If user allows, then the status is saved somewhere. I need to request user later to allow the app to use `LocationManager` in case it was set to "not allow".

Here is what I have:

```
var requestAuthorizationFunction = function()  {
    cordova.plugins.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
}
```

This `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` function is called only once. I need to be able to call it again to update the status. 
Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If authorization has already been granted, iOS will not re-present the dialog to the user, even if you call that method.  If the user has denied the authorization or has not yet answered, calling that method a second time will again present a dialog to the user.

In order to check if authorization has been granted, you can check `getAuthorizationStatus()` like this:

```
cordova.plugins.locationManager.getAuthorizationStatus()
    .then(function(authorized){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. Is there a way to update or remove the status and to show that request dialog again?

Comment: The end-user can go to settings for the app, and revoke the permission at any time.  However, there is no way to programmatically remove the permission.